# HTML code form Angular2 component property

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, angular, ng2-bootstrap

Following through the example to generate tabs view with ng2-bootstrap from http://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/, I have the following code:

```
<tabset>
<tab *ngFor="#tabz of tabs"
     [heading]="tabz.title"
     [active]="tabz.active"
     (select)="tabz.active = true"
     (deselect)="tabz.active = false"
     [disabled]="tabz.disabled"
     [removable]="tabz.removable"
     (removed)="removeTabHandler(tabz)">
    {{tabz?.content}}
</tab>
```

But I want to have HTML code to be pulled from the {{tabz?.content}} property. Is there a way to do this? My tabs array looks like this:

```
public tabs:Array<any> = [
{title: 'Summary View', content: 'Dynamic content 1', active: true},
{title: 'Search View', content: '<someAngularComponent>Error Displaying Entry view</someAngularComponent >'}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<tabset>
<tab *ngFor="#tabz of tabs"
     [heading]="tabz.title"
     [active]="tabz.active"
     (select)="tabz.active = true"
     (deselect)="tabz.active = false"
     [disabled]="tabz.disabled"
     [removable]="tabz.removable"
     (removed)="removeTabHandler(tabz)"
     [innerHTML]="tabz?.content">
</tab>
```

You should be aware that Angular doesn't sanitize the HTML and doesn't process it any other way. Bindings like `[]`, `()`, `{{}}`, `<my-comp>`, `<div myDirective>` are ignored by Angular by HTML added this way.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm kind of new to front end development. Is there any way/recommendation for sanitizing the HTML?

Comment: You also said that <my-comp>, <div myDirective> are ignored by Angular. Do you mean even if these are a part of the [innerHTML] content? If so how would I go about loading a Angular component within the innerHTML?

Comment: There isn't much you can do with dynamic HTML from Angular. When you have static HTML like `<div #someTarget></div>` then you can use [DynamicComponentLoader](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/DynamicComponentLoader-class.html) to add components to `#someTarget`.

Answer (score 1):

Plain html injection:

```
<tab [innerHTML]="tabz?.content">
```

Angular2 templates/components can not be injected in the same way as above, you could wrap content into component and load it using `DynamicComponentLoader` triggered by `(select)` event.

Comment: Kind of new to this... could you provide reference/example for using the DynamicComponentLoader on the (select) event?

Comment: There is good [example](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/DynamicComponentLoader-class.html) in the official documentation.

Comment: html injection did the trick for me. Btw, not that I want, but the link in the previous example is dead. Also seems with final release of angular, DynamicComponentLoader is no longer available.